# How to make Scrapy general purpose?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy for scraping text from websites.
I would like Scrapy to scrape text from various URLs with different structure, without having to change the code for each website.

The following example works in my Jupyter Notebook for the given URL ( http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/ ). But it does not work for another (for ex.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping ).
My question is, how to make it work for (most) other websites without manually inspecting every site and changing the code all the time? I guess I need to make a change under `def parse(self, response)`, but so far I could not find a good example how to do that.

Modules:

```
import scrapy
import scrapy.crawler as crawler
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

Spider:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            print(quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first())
```

A wrapper to make it run more times in Jupyter:

```
def run_spider(spider):
    def f(q):
        try:
            runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
            deferred = runner.crawl(spider)
            deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
            reactor.run()
            q.put(None)
        except Exception as e:
            q.put(e)

    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    result = q.get()
    p.join()

    if result is not None:
        raise result
```

Get the result:

```
 print('Extracted text:')
 run_spider(QuotesSpider)
```

Extracted text:

```
“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, ..."
```

Comment: Where is you error?

Comment: If all the websites have the same structure of data you want to scarp you can put all the website URLs in start_urls list. If any site has no 'div.quote' or the same structure you need to make another spider.

Comment: In this code, there is no error. But if you use another URL, for ex.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping, it will most of the times not work.

Comment: @Utnubu Please verify that the website which is not working has 'div.quote' or same structure as the website which is working fine.

Comment: @Meha Parekh: That is actually the question. I do not want to check manually for every website, is there something instead of `div.quote` that works for most websites?

Comment: If the website has the same structure then it must work otherwise it will not work you can put website URL in start_urls one by one and can check. If it will work data will be printed else it will throw an error.

Comment: If multiple URLs that I scrape have a different structure, is there a way to change the code that it can still automatically deal with these differences?

Comment: Most sites will have different structure thus a different selector for the data you want. You could probably develop something that works pretty well for say blog sites....input parameters to find the data or for example shopify stores are mostly the same.

Comment: Have you tried using magic (machine learning)?